# SSH pem/private-key based login error?

Tags: ssh, aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I just created an ec2-instance with Amazon Linux 2 OS, then logged in to the system using login: `ec2-user` and an associated privatekey. Next, I created a new user `x` and copied the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file from the `ec2-user` home directory to the `x` user home directory. Finally, I changed ownership of the `authorized_keys` file to `x`.

```
sudo ls -ald /home/x/.ssh
drwxrwxr-x 2 x x 29 Sep 18 16:42 /home/x/.ssh
```

and

```
sudo ls -al /home/x/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 x x 387 Sep 18 16:42 /home/x/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now when I am logging as user `x` using the same private key, I am getting the error shown below:

```
ssh -i /some/path/aws/privatekey.pem x@a.b.c.d
x@a.b.c.d: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

How might one fix this so a successful login is possible?

(Does the `authorized_keys` file hold any user information too.)

A similar question that did not help: [ssh : Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300446/ssh-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-with-mic)

Answer (score 1):

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 x x 29 Sep 18 16:42 /home/x/.ssh
```

Your `/home/x/.ssh` has group write permission set, so theoretically another member of group `x` might have been able to tamper with the contents of the directory. And so, out of an abundance of caution, `sshd` will ignore the `authorized_keys` file.

The `sshd(8)` man page says:

> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
>
> If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory are writable by other users, then the file could be modified or replaced by unauthorized users. In this case, sshd will not allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to “no”.

To fix it:

```
chmod go-w / /home /home/x /home/x/.ssh
```

Also, `/` and `/home` should of course be owned by root.

A user can grant others write access to *other sub-directories* of their home directory, but the home directory itself and the `~/.ssh/` sub-directory are security-sensitive and should always be writable for the user owning the directory only. There are many files (e.g. the `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` and similar login scripts) in the home directory that could be used for evil if they are left writeable for others.

Before SSH was developed, the `~/.rhosts` file used by the old `rsh`/`rlogin`/`rcp` tools had similar protection requirements - and was similarly ignored if not adequately protected.

Comment: `sudo ls -lrd /home/x/.ssh/` output:
`drwx------ 2 x x 29 Sep 18 18:42 /home/x/.ssh/` and it fixed. thx